# Does weak convergence imply convergence under this special norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider $H$  be a separable Hilbertian space with real inner product $\langle , \rangle $. Let $\Gamma: H \to H$ be a Nuclear operator
$$\Gamma(u) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n \langle u, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n$$
And it's squared root (which is a compact operator)
$$\Gamma^{1/2}(u) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n^{1/2} \langle u, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n$$
Where $(\phi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ form an orthonormal basis for H. And $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \ldots > 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n < \infty$
Now let's define the norm associated to $\Gamma$
$$ \| u \|^2_{\star} = \| \Gamma^{1/2} (u) \|^2  = \sum_{i=1}^\infty  \lambda_i \langle u, \phi_i\rangle^2  $$

**Does weak convergence implies convergence in the new norm ?**

i.e $$\langle u_n, v \rangle \to \langle u , v\rangle \quad \forall v \in H \implies \| u_n - u \|_\star \to 0 $$

It is easy to see the converse does not hold because  $\| \lambda_n^{-1/2} \phi_n \|_{\star}^2 = \lambda_n^{1/2} \to 0$ but $\lambda_n^{-1/2} \phi_n$ is unbounded which contradicts the uniform boundness principle.

Comment: The fact that $u_n\rightharpoonup\ \Rightarrow\lVert T u_n-T u\rVert\to 0$ hold in general for every compact operator $T$. All the other properties of $\Gamma^{1/2}$ play no role in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n\rightharpoonup u$. Fix some index $N$. Then
$$
\|u_n-u\|_*^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i\langle u-u_n,\phi_i\rangle^2
 = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\langle u-u_n,\phi_i\rangle^2 + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty \lambda_i\langle u-u_n,\phi_i\rangle^2\\
\le \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\langle u-u_n,\phi_i\rangle^2 + \lambda_{N+1}\|u-u_n\|^2,
$$
where the inequality follows from the monotonicity of $(\lambda_i)$ and the Parseval identity. Now choose $N$ large enough such that the second addend becomes small. Then the first addend can be made small for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 3):

From the compactness of $\Gamma^{1/2}$,
the weak convergence $u_n \rightharpoonup u$
implies $\Gamma^{1/2} (u_n - u) \to 0$,
hence $\|u_n - u\|_\star \to 0$.

Comment: A proof of this for any compact operator would invole writing $\Gamma^{1/2}(u) = \sum \lambda_j \langle u, f_j \rangle e_j$ for $(e_j), \, (f_j)$ orthonormal basis  and a similar argument to daw's. answe?r  Or is it something more elegant and fundamental?

Comment: This holds for any compact operator $T$. Suppose that $\{T \, x_n\}$ does not converge to $T\,x$. Thus, there is a subsequence $\{T \, x_{n_k}\}$ with $\| T x - T x_{n_k}\| \ge \varepsilon > 0$. Since $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is bounded, $\{T x_{n_k}\}$ has a convergent subsequence. Since $T \, x_n \rightharpoonup T \, x$, the limit point of this subsequence has to be $T \, x$ and this yields a contradiction.